# Javascript naming class by variable

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have `p` element like this :

```
<p class="11"></p>
```

I try to change the content by `append()` method through clear.js like this :

```
$('.11').append("taylor");
```

it works fine and print "taylor" on my page, but if I change my code like this :

```
number=11;
classProv = "'." + number + "'";
$(classProv).append("taylor");
```

it returns error message :`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.11'`

Why did it happen ? Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're including some extra quotation marks. Drop the extra quotes and it works just fine.

```js
number=11;
classProv = "." + number;
$(classProv).append("taylor");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="11"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember.

If you write

```
 $('.11').append("taylor");
```

You provide a string as parameter explicitly. By declaring a variable like `var classProv = '.' + number;` and using it as parameter you provide a string. So there is no additional quotes needed.

Answer (score 0):

The string you are concatenating ends up literally being `"'.11'"`, which contains single quotes in the value.

What you need is:

```
var number = 11;
var classProv = "." + number;
```